# Accessing Auth from Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am having trouble accessing user information from the Firebase Cloud Functions environment.

What I am trying to do.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin') 
admin.initializeApp() 
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest(() => {   
    admin.auth().getUser('<user_id>').then(user => {
        return console.log(user)   
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e)   
    })
 })
```

Now, when I run the `test` function, I get the following error.

```
{ code: 'auth/insufficient-permission',
 message: 'Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property has insufficient permission to access the requested resource. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for details on how to authenticate this SDK with appropriate permissions.' }, 
 codePrefix: 'auth' }
```

Now, my question is that if it is possible to use `admin.auth().getUser` from the cloud functions environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need credentials file which you pass to admin sdk initialize function. Auth related task need this configuration in cloud functions.

Go to you Firebase C*onsole -> Settings -> Project Settings -> Service Accounts -> Generate new private key*.

Download the file and include in you code.

P.S: make sure this file is **not shared to public** in any form (add it to git ignore), since have this file gives full access to you firebase project.

Comment: or you can just add `Service Account Token Creator` to your IAM credentials, firebase functions will automatically be a safe environment

Comment: Fail to see how this answers the question. I got this error whilst using a service account.